# How to Limit Number of Users Logging into the application?

Tags: java, struts2, web.xml, struts-config

I have made an application in Java(Struts Framework).

Is there a direct way or web.xml mapping or something else from where i can **restrict the number of users** logged in my application.

At present, I want only 2 users to login in my web application. Also, i can change the number any time. so want to make it a dynamic application.

**P.S. :** Don't want to use the traditional servlet concept of static variable and all as its creating problem in my application.

Comment: Please help people. Its urgent.

Comment: Avoid asking for "urgent" stuff if you don't wanna be downvoted hard...

Answer (score 0):

So our goal is to store the current number of logged in user, be able to read it, and be able to modify it by some means. We have a number of alternatives to static variable:

- Store the number in an ordinary file in file system
- Store the number in a database engine data table
- Run an external memory cache

Comment: Hi Howard,
Thanx for ur reply. I did the stuff by DBMS but the problem occurring is when the session expire or someone close the browser how can i maintain the record(as i need to decrease the counter).

Comment: The common practice is to wait until user makes the next request, and we determine whether user's previous session has expired - if it is so, then we have to maintain (subtract one) the correctness of number of logged in user, eventually determine whether the number limit has been reached.